# SQLite: does data type depend on the quotes?

Tags: sqlite

In SQLite, the datatype of a value is associated with the value itself, not with the column type. So suppose we have a table with an integer primary key "id" and an integer column "some_number". If I do a query like this:

```
INSERT INTO mytable (id, some_number) VALUES (NULL, "1234")
```

Will 123 be inserted as an integer or as string? What consequences it will have later for me, say, when I'm comparing it with other value like "234" (as a number 1234 > 234, as a string "1234" < "234", right?)?

Comment: But the standard for string literals in SQLite is single quotes `'` not double quotes `"`. While its true that double-quotes work, that is a convenience; double-quotes are supposed to be used for identifiers.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

if your field type, (some_number), is numeric,  then it will be inserted as a numeric value. No matter whether you put quotes.

if some_numeber is numeric

```
INSERT INTO mytable (id, some_number) VALUES (NULL, "1234")
```

and

```
INSERT INTO mytable (id, some_number) VALUES (NULL, 1234)
```

are same

Answer (score 2):

It depends on the [type affinity](http://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html#affinity) of the column.

Comment: But given the automatic conversions described in that doc, the end result is the same, for a given type affinity. `TEXT` will convert `1234` to `"1234"`. `Numeric` will convert `"1234"` to `1234`. etc. Therefore the quotes do not affect the end result.